# Get the $k$-th permutation of $n$ distinct items ignoring direction.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a set of $n$ distinct items, and I want to retrieve the $k$-th lexically-sorted permutation, yet ignoring its direction (e.g. [1,2,3,4] = [4,3,2,1]). These elements would be considered duplicates.

Since all $n$ elements are distinct, we know each permutation has one exact duplicate (its reversed form). Therefore, there are $\frac{n!}{2}$ different permutations.

Now, let's say I have $k \in [0, \frac{n!}{2} - 1]$. I would like to get the $k$-th permutation, but ignoring duplicates.

**Example**: let's say I have $n = 4$, items being numbers $1...4$. I have $4! = 24$ permutations:

| Permutation | k | k (ign. duplicates) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $(1,2,3,4)$ | $0$ | $0$ |
| $(1,2,4,3)$ | $1$ | $1$ |
| $(1,3,2,4)$ | $2$ | $2$ |
| $(1,3,4,2)$ | $3$ | $3$ |
| $(1,4,2,3)$ | $4$ | $4$ |
| $(1,4,3,2)$ | $5$ | $5$ |
| $(2,1,3,4)$ | $6$ | $6$ |
| $(2,1,4,3)$ | $7$ | $7$ |
| $(2,3,1,4)$ | $8$ | $8$ |
| $(2,3,4,1)$ | $9$ | (repeated) |
| $(2,4,1,3)$ | $10$ | $9$ |
| $(2,4,3,1)$ | $11$ | (repeated) |
| $(3,1,2,4)$ | $12$ | $10$ |
| $(3,1,4,2)$ | $13$ | (repeated) |
| $(3,2,1,4)$ | $14$ | $11$ |
| $(3,2,4,1)$ | $15$ | (repeated) |
| $(3,4,1,2)$ | $16$ | (repeated) |
| $(3,4,2,1)$ | $17$ | (repeated) |
| $(4,1,2,3)$ | $18$ | (repeated) |
| $(4,1,3,2)$ | $19$ | (repeated) |
| $(4,2,1,3)$ | $20$ | (repeated) |
| $(4,2,3,1)$ | $21$ | (repeated) |
| $(4,3,1,2)$ | $22$ | (repeated) |
| $(4,3,2,1)$ | $23$ | (repeated) |

I'm currently using Factorial Number System to get the $k$-th permutation, but I cannot figure out the way to ignore duplicate items.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's a palindrome in this context?  Usually a palindrome would be something like $abcdedcba$, which reads the same backwards and forwards....but permutations of distinct letters can't look like that.

Comment: Are you saying that, since $1234$ is in the list, $4321$ can't be?  And then, of the pair, you always select the one that starts with the smaller value? That's not what "palindrome" means.   But, really, you should edit for clarity.

Comment: Hi @lulu, you are totally right. I've updated the question and hopefully is clearer now :)

Comment: Much better (+1). To do it, I'd work the same way one does for unrestricted permutations.  Note that your list is precisely this list permutations such that the first character is less than the last.  Thus there are $(n-1)!$ that begin with $1$, and there are $(n-2)\times (n-2)!$ that begin with $2$ (pick the last character, which can't be $1$, then permute the others.  And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the discussion in the comments:

This can be handled in essentially the same way one enumerates the unrestricted permutations.

First, note that this list is precisely the list of permutations for which the first character is less than the last. Call such a permutation "good". (Note: we are, of course, assuming that $n>1$.  The case $n=1$ is degenerate in that the unique permutation equals its reverse.)  For $n>1$ there are exactly $\frac {n!}2$ good permutations.

With that in mind, for $i\in \{1, \cdots, n\}$ let $f(i)$ denote the number of good permutations that start with $i$. Thus $f(1)=(n-1)!$ and $f(n)=0$.  With $i=2$ we see that all the permutations are good except for those that end in $1$.  Thus, to get a good permutation, we must select a final character from $\{3, \cdots, n\}$  and then permute the rest.  Thus $f(2)=(n-2)\times (n-2)!$.  Similarly, $$f(i)=(n-i)\times (n-2)!$$

And if $i<j$ let $f(i, j)$ denote the number of good permutations that begin with $i$ and end with $j$.  Clearly $$f(i,j)=(n-2)!$$

Now, to find the $k^{th}$ good permutation, we first determine it's first digit.  That's the least level $N$ for which $$ \sum_{i=1}^{N+1}f(i)>k$$

Now we determine the last character.  We do that similarly, by adding $f(N, j)$ to $\sum_{i=1}^{N+1}f(i)$ until we exceed $k$.

Once we have the first and last character, we are just down to counting ordinary permutations which can be done in the ordinary way.

Comment: Hi @lulu, thank you for your response. I see the process, clearer, but I'm still having some troubles to come up with an algorithm for this process. 

First, when you say $j < i$, I think you mean $i < j$, right? Also, I get the process for determining the first digit, but cannot see the logic for the last one.

Finally, the problem boils down to counting permutations of the $(n - 2)$ inner items. Now, I won't be looking for the $k$-th, but for some $k'$-th ($k' \in [0, (n - 2)! - 1]$, how is this new 'counter' computed?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I meant $i<j$.  I'll edit.

Comment: For the last character...well, since we know the values of $f(i,j)$ we can just increment $j$ one by one until we pass the level $k$.  After that...well, I assumed you knew how to solve the problem for ordinary permutations.  If not, you should look that up. That's a necessary step.

Comment: It's the same as this, of course.  Count those that begin with $i$.  Then those that begin with $ij$ and so on.It's straight forward, but definitely inelegant.